# How to test `call(fn, params)` with redux-saga

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, redux-saga

I'm seeing some strange results when testing what I thought were simple saga's with redux-saga. 
Take this saga for example:

```
export function* initSaga() {

  yield call(window.clearTimeout, runner)

  yield call(PubSub.publishSync, 'RESET_CORE')

}
```

My mental model of the test reads, first check it called window.clearTimeout with a parameter which matches the value of `runner` then test it called the `publishSync` method of PubSub with the value 'RESET_CORE'

My test for the first part reads:

```
describe('when testing the init saga', () => {

  const saga = initSaga()
  const runner = null 

  it('first clears the draw loop for the canvas', () => {

    const result = saga.next().value
    const expected = call(window.clearInterval, runner)

    console.log(result)
    console.log(expected)

    expect(result).to.deep.equal(expected)

  })
})
```

What's frustrating is that the error message reads:

```
AssertionError: expected { Object (@@redux-saga/IO, CALL) } to deeply equal { Object (@@redux-saga/IO, CALL) }
```

And my console logs read:

```
 console.log src\tests\sagas\simulatorSaga.test.js:25
    { '@@redux-saga/IO': true,
      CALL:
       { context: null,
         fn: [Function: bound stopTimer],
         args: [ null ] } }

  console.log src\tests\sagas\simulatorSaga.test.js:26
    { '@@redux-saga/IO': true,
      CALL:
       { context: null,
         fn: [Function: bound stopTimer],
         args: [ null ] } }
```

Which to me look identical. I'm presuming there is something simple I'm missing here, some kind of deep equal object reference kind of stuff but I'm not sure bearing in mind the saga and test how I could make this any more cut down.

I'm aware that the whole `window` + `pubsub` isn't exactly how saga's are meant to be used, but the app is interfacing with a canvas for running a simulation so we kind of have to do it that way.

Comment: I posted a question about your question too long for the comment box [in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162559/question-chat-for-48104000)

Comment: I see that you're trying to check if `window.clearTimeout` is equal to `window.clearInterval`.

Comment: That may be a typo, I will check in a couple of hours, if it's not *facepalm* :s

Comment: @ApoorvJoshi it was not a typo, you're caught it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that that's what the official docs suggest but I don't like such testing. It looks a little bit like testing if `redux-saga` does its job. What you are really interested in is if `clearInterval` and `publishSync` are executed with correct parameters. You don't care what the generator returns. So here's what I'm suggesting:

```
const executeSaga = function (saga) {
  var result = saga.next();

  while(!result.done) {
    result = saga.next();
  }
}

describe('when testing the init saga', () => {

  const runner = null;

  it('first clears the draw loop for the canvas', () => {
    sinon.stub(window, 'clearInterval');
    sinon.stub(PubSub, 'publishSync');
    executeSaga(initSaga());

    expect(window.clearInterval)
      .to.be.calledOnce
      .and.to.be.calledWith(runner);

    expect(PubSub.publishSync)
      .to.be.calledOnce
      .and.to.be.calledWith('RESET_CORE');

    window.clearInterval.restore();
    PubSub.publishSync.restore();
  })
})
```

It involves `sinonjs`. We are stubbing both functions, run the whole saga and then expect the stubs.

Comment: interesting, I was just having this discussion with a colleague about the impl being tied to the test a bit much.
What you've described seems like a much nicer way with less brittleness, ty